# Hive: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, hive

I am trying to setup PostgreSQL for Hive. This is the content of `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all   postgres                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all   postgres             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all   postgres             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident

local  all  ambari,mapred md5
host  all   ambari,mapred 0.0.0.0/0  md5
host  all   ambari,mapred ::/0 md5
```

When I check connection, I get the error:

```
2018-04-15 23:48:49,573 - Check db_connection_check was unsuccessful. Exit code: 1. Message: Apr 15, 2018 11:48:49 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl log
WARNING: SQLException occurred while connecting to master1.local.test.org:5432
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.0.10", user "hive", database "hive", SSL off
```

I tried to add a new line to `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` and restart PostgreSQL using `systemctl restart postgresql` (Centos 7):

```
host   hive   hive     192.168.0.10    trust
```

But then I get another error:

> Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited
>   with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working.
Give Subnet after IP address.

ex.

```
host    all   postgre           IP-Adress/subnet         trust
host    all   postgres          IP-Adress/subnet         trust

host    all   hive              IP-Adress/subnet         trust
host    all   hive              IP-Adress/subnet         trust
```